# A c++ program that stores the positions of each bit 1 in a binary sequence

Tags: c++

I have made this code to store the position of each bit 1 entered in a binary sequence. The output of the program is not what it is desired. The output I get for 10100 is 0x7fff9109be00. Here is the code:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <bitset>
using namespace std;

    int main()
    {
     bitset <5> inpSeq;
     int x = 0;
     int xorArray[x];
     unsigned int i;
     cout << "Enter a 5-bit sequence: \n";
     cin >> inpSeq;
     for ( i = 0; i < inpSeq.size(); i++)
     {
      if ( inpSeq[i] == 1 )
      {
      x = x+1;
      xorArray[x] = i; 
      }
     }
     cout << xorArray << "\n";
    }
```

Update for clarity: What I had in mind was that 'cout << xorArray' will print bit 1's positions.

Comment: You'd like us to guess what IS desired, or you're going to tell us at midnight?

Comment: You are printing the memory address of the array, I think.

Comment: Sorry If I haven't been clear enough. The output is xorArray and it should be the list of bit 1's positions in the sequence. So If I entered 10100, the output should be 2 and 4.

Comment: @MohamedAhmed: Your assumption that `cout << someArray` prints a list of elements is misguided. That's probably your problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
cout << xorArray << "\n";
```

This does not print the elements of `xorArray`; it prints its address.

You must iterate ("loop over") it:

```
for (auto x : xorArray)
   cout << x << ' ';
cout << '\n';
```

Your other problem is that you're trying to use a variable-length array, which does not exist in C++. Use a vector instead.

*Now* [it gives you your desired output](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/e8a78d6441d9392a):

```
#include <iostream>
#include <bitset>
#include <vector>

using namespace std;

int main()
{
    bitset<5> inpSeq("10111");

    std::vector<int> xorArray;

    for (unsigned int i = 0; i < inpSeq.size(); i++) {
        if (inpSeq[i] == 1)
            xorArray.push_back(i);
    }

    for (auto x : xorArray)
        cout << x << ' ';
    cout << '\n';
}
```

If you're not using C++11 for whatever reason, you can perform that final loop the traditional way:

```
for (std::vector<int>::const_iterator it  = xorArray.begin(),
                                      end = xorArray.end(),
     it != end; ++it) {
    cout << *it << ' ';
}
```

Or the naive way:

```
for (unsigned int i = 0; i < xorArray.size(); i++)
    cout << xorArray[i] << ' ';
```

Comment: I am unfamiliar with the concept of iteration. May you please provide a link or a brief explanation?!

Comment: @MohamedAhmed: No you're not. You already did it. It means to loop over something. Your C++ book assuredly covers it.

Comment: @MohamedAhmed think of iterators as pointer-like variables that point to an element in a container: `.begin()` gives you the first element and `.end()` gives you on *after* the end of the container.

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit In your initial response you said "iterate over it", so I was confused. Thanks for the code.

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit I am not using C++11, I use c++98. And I don't know why am I using it! I just compile the code with 'g++ -Wall -o' on Ubuntu. And I think the naive way you mentioned should be xorArray.size not xorArray.length.

Answer (score 2):

I am a little unclear on exactly what you are trying to achieve, but I think the following might help.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <bitset>
#include <list>

using namespace std;

int main() {
    bitset<5> inpSeq;
    unsigned int i;
    list<int> xorList;
    cout << "Enter a 5-bit sequence: \n";
    cin >> inpSeq;

    for (i = 0; i < inpSeq.size(); ++i) {
        if (inpSeq[i] == 1) {
            xorList.push_back(i);
        }
    }

    for (list<int>::iterator list_iter = xorList.begin();
         list_iter != xorList.end(); list_iter++)
    {
        cout << *list_iter << endl;
    }

    return 0;
}
```

The reason why I am using a list is because you mentioned wanting to store the positions of the 1 bit. The list is being used as the container for those positions, in case you need them in another point in the program.

One of the problems with the original code was that you assigned variable 'x' the value 0. When you declared xorArray[x], that meant you were essentially creating an array of length 0. This is incorrect syntax. It looks like you actually were trying to dynamically allocate the size of the array at runtime. That requires a different syntax and usage of pointers. The list allows you to grow the data structure for each 1 bit that you encounter.

Also, you cannot print an array's values by using

```
cout << xorArray << endl
```

That will print the memory address of the first element in the array, so, xorArray[0]. Whenever you want to print the values of a data structure such as a list or array, you need to iterate across the structure and print the values one by one.  That is the purpose of the second for() loop in the above code.

Lastly, the values stored are in accordance with the 0 index. If you want positions that start with 1, you'll have to use

```
xorList.push_back(i+1);
```

Hope this helps!

Comment: I want to use the stored positions in a loop for an XOR operation of the bits that those positions point to. My final goal is a linear feedback shift register. Your code is perfect, but I really need to know what is wrong with mine.

Comment: I have updated my answer to explain my code and the changes needed from your original post.